# difference between map_instance[key] vs. map_instance.find(key) in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map defined as

```
static map<unsigned int, deque<FOO_STRUCT*> > CV_MAP;
```

and I was wondering if one method was better than the other between:

```
map_instance[key] vs. map_instance.find(key).
```

Comment: The two are not equivalent. Which one is better rather depends on what you need it for.

Comment: I'm afraid to ask, but have you looked at descriptions of these methods before asking?

Comment: Perhaps you need [a `std::map` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: Yeah I must have misinterpreted the docs, sorry I'm very new to c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map_instance[key]` will default construct a new value for the key `key` if it is not present.

As in, it will call `deque<FOO_STRUCT*>`'s constructor if `key` is not present, and return the newly constructed `deque<FOO_STRUCT*>`.

Using the `find` member function will not construct a new value for the given key-- when the key is absent, it will just return an iterator that points to `CV_MAP.end()`.

Use what's appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

`map_instance[key]` - return **reference** (before, if need, construct new element)
`map_instance.find(key)` - return **iterator**

Answer (score 0):

`map_instance[key]` can be preferred where all you care is put the key  with default initialization into the map, if not present, or do something with it if present.

Consider a case where you want to store count of each element in an array.

```
for(auto x : array){
   map_instance[x]++;  //no need to find here at first. 
}
```

As you can see it really simplifies your code, and gets rid of `if-else` clause.

```
for(auto x : array){
   if ( map_instance.find(key) == map_instance.end() ) {
      map_instance[x] = 0;
   }
   else{
      map_instance[x]++;
   }
}
```